# How to align a poster?

Tags: image-processing, image, geometric-transform

I'd like to crop and transform out the magazine cover so that it is rectangular.

[image]

I read the docs for `ImagePerspectiveTransformation`, and here's where I got to. First, I found the bounding polygon top-left top-right, bottom-right and bottom-left points:

```
img = Import@
"http://www.vinylbanner.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/\
1800x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/s/l/slanted-magic-mount-3.jpg";
corners = {{212.29296875`, 156.265625`}, {594.69921875`, 
  157.5703125`}, {489.16796875`, 424.98828125`}, {236.30859375`, 430.54296875`}};
```

Assuming its aspect ratio is 11 by 8.5 and it is 100 pixels tall:

```
h = 100;
w = (8.5/11)*h;
ft = FindGeometricTransform[corners, {{0, h}, {w, h}, {0, w}, {0, 0}}]
new = ImagePerspectiveTransformation[img, ft[[2]]]
```

but I get an error:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure those corners are coordinates? They more like RGB values.

Comment: Yup, sorry bout that, fixed!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A few minor mistakes:

- `corners` and the target coordinates weren't in the same order
- For some reasons, pixels isn't the default unit for `ImagePerspectiveTransformation` and friends - you have to specify `PlotRange` and `DataRange` explicitly
- the target coordinates should go first in `FindGeometricTransform` - alternatively, you can pass `InverseFunction@ft[[2]]` to `ImagePerspectiveTransformation`

Which leads to this result:

```
h = 300;
w = (8.5/11)*h;
ft = FindGeometricTransform[{{0, 0}, {w, 0}, {w, h}, {0, h}}, corners]
new = ImagePerspectiveTransformation[img, ft[[2]], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, w}, {0, h}}, DataRange -> Full]
```

[image]

Comment: @nikkie thanks!