# How to segment rectangular photographs on a table?

Tags: image-processing

Given an image of a table with photographs (take from any angle), I'm trying to **extract the photographs and correctly align them** into perfect rectangles. There are four steps to the algorithm:

1. Detect quadrangles in the input image
2. Filter out non-photograph quadrangles
3. Re-project the quadrangles to a bird's-eye view
4. Correct for curved edges in the sub-images

Here's an example of doing the first two steps:

[image]

- For each of detected photographic quadrangles an orange outline is drawn.
- I've added a green one to emphasize the fidelity of solution I'm looking for, we can't lose any pixels in this process.
- Notice how the orange rectangles do not contain any white margins - we just want them to shrink-wrap the photographic content.

Ok, then here's what the remaining steps look like:

[image]

Note that for each of reprojected photograph (shown on the left) we fix the warping/curvature of the photograph by transforming it into a perfectly rectangular image (on the right).

Here's an example image to try:

```
Import @ CloudObject[
 "https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/d3999fcf-7a01-4d60-bb9c-38604d252475"]
```

And as requested, some additional examples to test with:

```
CloudGet @ CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/068cf32f-b753-4c38-bc01-f378bc64d54a"]
```

[image]

Comment: [How to peel the labels from marmalade jars using Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5676/731) is a possible duplicate.

Comment: Although, in your example image you have a photograph that has an unknown curvature. At least in the case of the marmalade jars, the surface of the labels could be described in cylindrical coordinates. In this case, it is not clear how to infer and describe how the photograph is curved, which is probably much harder.

Comment: @C.E. I think it's actually related to the inverse of the bottle-label problem

Comment: See `ImagePerspectiveTransformation`.

Comment: @C.E. I've updated to problem to elaborated more on how the bottle-label solution doesn't solve it

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I think `ImagePerspectiveTransformation` will help to re-project the image but we would have to assume a fixed aspect (the most common print aspects are 5x7, 4x6, 8x10). But deriving correct segmentations in step 1 and 2 is the hardest part IMO

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/126135/242

Comment: Do you already have some code to extract the separate photos? Could you publish that?

Comment: Your test image is a harder version of the problem than the first image in your post ;) The lighting is much harder, the background is not a uniform color, some photos are cut off by the border.

Comment: @CarlLange sorry, I don’t have any code yet

Comment: @M.R. I doubt anybody will be able to solve the problem for the test image that you give - that conditions simply are too difficult. Consider a better test image!

Comment: @CarlLange ok I found a few more test images

Comment: @M.R. Doesn't look like your question is updated with them. I reiterate that the first image in your question is about 20 times easier to do this for than the image you post as an example at the end of your question.

Comment: @CarlLange just added them!

Answer (score 8):

Here's an idea, but it only works (partially) with the easiest of the test cases.

```
img = CloudGet[CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/068cf32f-b753-4c38-bc01-\
f378bc64d54a"]][[5]]
```

[image]

```
(* Binarize - this step depends a lot on the background in the image *)
img2 = ChanVeseBinarize[img, Automatic, {Automatic, Automatic, 2, 1}]
```

[image]

```
(* Find hulls, and discard ones that are tiny or touching a border *)
comps = MorphologicalComponents[img2, Method -> "ConvexHull"];
comps2 = SelectComponents[comps, #AdjacentBorderCount == 0 && #Count > 50 &];

(* show perimeters, to see how it's working *)
perims = ComponentMeasurements[comps2, "PerimeterPositions"];
HighlightImage[img, {PointSize[Medium], Red, Point @@@ perims[[All, 2]]}]
```

[image]

```
(* Extract the single images *)
singleimgs = ComponentMeasurements[ {comps2, img} , "MaskedImage"][[All, 2]]
```

[image]

```
transform[img_] := 
 Module[{img2, frame, comp, p, c, c2, cornerdemo, t, img3},
  
  (*add some padding,to make the corner detection work better*)
  img2 = ImagePad[img, 2];
  
  (*get the perimeter of the image*)
  frame = AlphaChannel[img2];
  comp = MorphologicalComponents[frame, Method -> "ConvexHull"];
  p = Flatten[
    ComponentMeasurements[comp, "PerimeterPositions"][[1, 2]], 1];
  
  (*find the corners of the image*)
  c = Sort[ImageCorners[frame, 5, 0.01]];
  
  (*the desired new corners*)
  c2 = Sort[Tuples[MinMax /@ Transpose[p]]];
  
  (*just to demonstrate the corner detection*)
  colors = {Red, Orange, Yellow, Blue};
  cornerdemo = 
   Show[frame, 
    Graphics[{Table[{colors[[n]], Disk[c2[[n]], 5]}, {n, 4}]}], 
    Graphics[Table[{colors[[n]], Circle[c[[n]], 5]}, {n, 4}]]];
  
  (*transform such that the image corners are mapped to the desired corners*)
  t = Last[FindGeometricTransform[c2, c]];
  img3 = ImagePerspectiveTransformation[img2, t, DataRange -> Full];
  
  {cornerdemo, img3}]

transform /@ singleimgs
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

With some of the examples given, we can bring all the images in the correct position at once, before extracting them. Here I chose 4 points using the coordinates tool.

[image]

```
imgs = CloudGet@
   CloudObject[
    "https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/068cf32f-b753-4c38-bc01-\
f378bc64d54a"];

fourPoints = {{43.8398, 70.2148}, {336.398, 68.4375}, {342.199, 219.031}, {56.6094,209.16}}
```

This function processes the image. It takes the image and the four points.

```
processImage[img_, pts_List] := (
  rect = {{pts[[1]][[1]], pts[[1]][[2]]}, {pts[[3]][[1]], 
     pts[[1]][[2]]}, {pts[[3]][[1]], pts[[3]][[2]]}, {pts[[1]][[1]], 
     pts[[3]][[2]]}};
  transform = FindGeometricTransform[rect, pts][[2]];
  Show[fullImage = 
    Sharpen[ImagePerspectiveTransformation[img, transform, 
      PlotRange -> Full], 1], 
   Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Green, Point[rect], Transparent, 
     EdgeForm[Green], Polygon[rect]}], ImageSize -> Medium]
  )

processImage[imgs[[1]],fourPoints];
```

[image]

Now we isolate the pictures.

```
perim = MorphologicalPerimeter[fullImage, 60];
i2 = DeleteSmallComponents[perim];
morphBox = MorphologicalTransform[i2, {"BoundingBoxes", "Clean"}, Infinity]; 
ima=ImageMultiply[fullImage,morphBox];
```

[image]

Extract as a list of images and discard those not meeting a certain dimensions.

```
singles = ComponentMeasurements[ima, "MaskedImage"][[All, 2]];
validSingles = 
 Select[singles, 
  0.4 < Min[ImageDimensions[#]]/Max[ImageDimensions[#]] &]
```

Go through the list of images and attempt to trim the borders. It is difficult to get something that will work for all images, particularly when the border is the same color as the background of the photo. This works for some images, but not all of them.

```
imageList = {};
n = 1;
While[n <= Length[validSingles],
 v = validSingles[[n]];
 dim = ImageDimensions[v];
 bd = BorderDimensions[ImageAdjust[v, {-0.1, 0.1}], 0.04];
 crop1 = ImageCrop[v, 
   dim - {bd[[1]][[1]], bd[[2]][[1]]}, {Left, Bottom}];
 dim2 = ImageDimensions[crop1];
 crop2 = ImageCrop[crop1, 
   dim2 - {bd[[1]][[2]], bd[[2]][[2]]}, {Right, Top}];
 AppendTo[imageList, crop2];
 n++;
 ]
Row[imageList, "  "]
```

[image]

Better with a black background.

[image]